# How to get value of <a> tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have this code:

```
<html>
<BUTTON ONCLICK="stups()">VALUE FINDER </BUTTON>
<a value="this is a value" href="value"><img src="b5.jpg"> values rule!!</a>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a").value
function stups(){

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=a

}
</script>


</html>
```

The javascript is simply meant to get the value of th (link) when the button is clicked I don't even know what is supposed to be the value whether it is th `href` attribute, the `value` attribute ,the value of the `img` attribute or the text in between the two `<a>`and `</a>`,well I've tried EVERYTHING i could think of and it never gives me any value it keeps giving me the word   `undefined`.Please help.

> **NB**:I *need* that  to be in between the `<a></a>` because it is a link

Thanks in advance

Comment: The "value" attribute is non-standard for `<a>` tags and means nothing to the browser. However, you can get it using `.getAttribute("value")`. Also `.getElementsByTagName()` returns a *list* of elements, and you have to index or iterate to get the individual nodes.

Comment: thanks but where should i put `.getAttribute("value").`?

Comment: Well your intentions aren't very clear; your own question indicates that you're not even sure which attribute you want to get or how you want to identify the `<a>` relevant to the button click among all the `<a>` tags that may be on the page.

Comment: If you want to control where the `a` tag is going to take you when you click it, set the `href` attribute and not the `value` attribute.

Comment: UPPERCASE is considered shouting online, please refrain from using it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, take care of what you want to do, because `.getElementsByTagName("a")` will return you a collection of elements.

Then, you might want to use `.getAttribute("value")`:

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

function stups(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a[0].getAttribute("value");
}
```

```html
<BUTTON ONCLICK="stups()">VALUE FINDER </BUTTON>
<a value="this is a value" href="value"><img src="b5.jpg"> values rule!!</a>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

If you want to manage multiple `a` elements, you could do the following:

- Use a `.querySelectorAll("a")`, to be able to use a `forEach` loop directly,
- `.push()` your values in an array,
- Do what you want with your array.

```js
var as = document.querySelectorAll("a");

function stups(){
  var values = [];
  as.forEach(function(a, index){
    values.push(a.getAttribute("value") || '--- no value ---');
    // OR: values.push(as[index].getAttribute("value"));
  })
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = values.join('<br>');
}
```

```html
<BUTTON ONCLICK="stups()">VALUE FINDER </BUTTON>
<a value="this is a value" href="value"><img src="b5.jpg"> values rule!!</a>
<a value="this is another value" href="value"><img src="b5.jpg"> values rule!!</a>
<a href="value"><img src="b5.jpg">No value here</a>
<a value="this is another value, again" href="value"><img src="b5.jpg"> values rule!!</a>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I still think I should clarify the `value` of the `a` tag does not matter at all and probably should not be set. The `href` attribute is what the link actually leads to.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define which attribute you need from the `a` tag.

So try `.getAttribute('value')`

```html
<html>
<button onclick="stups()">VALUE FINDER </button>
<a value="this is a value" href="value"><img src="b5.jpg"> values rule!!</a>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>

function stups(){
   var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('value');
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=a

}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In these situations, [MDN is your friend.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) You also shouldn't be copy-pasting code you don't understand. The `src` of the `img` points to whatever image is being displayed. The `href` of the `a` tag is the actual link. The text inside the a tag is what shows up. You should not be setting the `value` attribute of the `a` tag as it is non-standard and not needed. `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` returns an array of every `a` tag in the document. You need to specify the first link by running `document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]`. You can get the link just by using `.href`. In the end, the `stups` function should look something like this:

```
function stups(){
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

Comment: What do u mean MDN is my friend??